# How can I access an EnvironmentObject from within a NSViewRepresentable/UIViewRepresentable's Coordinator class?

Tags: swift, swiftui, appkit, metalkit

I got an EnvironmentObject named `appState`, which is accessed through some of my views to share data/states. The way I use them in a view is like this:

```
struct MetalView: NSViewRepresentable {
@EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
```

How can I access `appState` from my view's Coordinator class?

When I try to call it in any way I've tried yet, I get this error:

> Instance member 'appState' of type 'MetalView' cannot be used on instance of nested type 'MetalView.Coordinator'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved this:

AppState.swift:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared = AppState()
    init () {} // TODO: was private init, find out if this has benefits
    
    @Published var currentView: String = "login"
    // add rest of shared stuff below
```

AppDelegate.swift:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let appState = AppState.shared
```

Access from SwiftUI Views:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
```

Access from NSViewRepresentable / UIViewRepresentable Coordinator Class:

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, MTKViewDelegate {
...  
        func draw(in view: MTKView) {
            ...
            context.render((AppState.shared.rawImage ?? AppState.shared.rawImageOriginal)!,
                to: drawable.texture,
                commandBuffer: commandBuffer,
                bounds: AppState.shared.rawImageOriginal!.extent,
                colorSpace: colorSpace)
    }
...
```